# Java Download for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse

I needs help actually i am trying to download java and eclipse. How can i download java for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) PPA. This will download the required files from Oracle and install JDK 8.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

After installation completes, you can check whether it succeeded with the command

`java -version`